# Iterating over arrays, each with a pair of values, to operate on each pair in turn

Tags: bash, shell, loops

I already know how to generate pairs by taking one variable from each of a set of arrays, as such:

```
#!/bin/bash
dir1=(foo baz)  # Not ideal: Want inputs to be dir1=(foo bar); dir2=(baz bat) instead
dir2=(bar bat)
for i in "${!dir1[@]}"
do
  echo "Comparing ${dir1[i]} to ${dir2[i]}"
done
```

Produces the following output.

> Comparing foo to bar
>   
>   Comparing baz to bat

---

Is there a way to do this loop with `foo bar` on the same line and `baz bat` on it's same line? As follows.

```
pair1=(foo bar)
pair2=(baz bat)
...
pairN=(qux quux)
...
do
  # then, inside the loop, compare the pair
done
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [bash How to declare and iterate over pairs of values where values may contain spaces (two dimensional array)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32871443/bash-how-to-declare-and-iterate-over-pairs-of-values-where-values-may-contain-sp)

Comment: You could use `echo -n ...`

Comment: Do you want to loop over the `pairX` arrays, and for each array compare the first and second element?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `${!prefix@}` to iterate over variable names starting with `prefix`, and [namerefs](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/commands/builtin/declare#nameref) to refer to content stored under each name:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
case $BASH_VERSION in ''|[123].*|4.[012].*) echo "ERROR: Bash 4.3 required" >&2; exit 1;; esac

pair1=(foo bar)
pair2=(baz bat)
pairN=(qux quux)

declare -n currPair
for currPair in "${!pair@}"; do
  echo "Comparing ${currPair[0]} to ${currPair[1]}"
done
```

See this running at https://ideone.com/pTehPZ

Comment: If you move the `declare -n` statement outside of the loop with `declare -n arrayName`, the nameref will be established for each value of `"${!pair@}"`, and you don't need to introduce a separate variable.

Comment: I'm not sure I like that syntax -- it feels magical (in terms of not having a good way to disambiguate whether the nameref is being retargeted, or its target's value is being updated).

Comment: Fair enough. I discovered the option only after always doing it like you show, and I prefer it for brevity.

Comment: Following my own link, though, I *do* see that it's documented (at least on the bash-hackers' wiki), so...

Comment: Also in the manual, [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameters): "If the control variable in a `for` loop has the nameref attribute, the list of words can be a list of shell variables, and a name reference will be established for each word in the list, in turn, when the loop is executed."