# how do I create an array with dynamic name in bash

Tags: bash

Example

I want to get the size of each arrangement.
I have a multidimensional arrangement.

```
array=("SRV_1=(e1 e2 e3 e4)" "SRV_2=(e1 e2)")

for elt in "${array[@]}";do eval $elt;done

CANT_SRVS="${#array[@]}

for ((i=1;i<=$CANT_SRVS;i++));do
  CANT_E="${#SRV_$i[@]}"    <------ ERROR
  echo $CANT_E          <------- length array
done
```

Comment: Not an exact duplicate, but you can use the technique from the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53733286/3266847).

Comment: Aside: `eval $elt` introduces bugs you don't have with `eval "$elt"` (which still is error-prone, but not quite as much so).

Comment: ...to showcase a specific issue with `eval $elt` vs `eval "$elt"`, btw, try running `set -x; elt="array=( ' * ' )"; eval $elt; declare -p elt` in a non-empty directory.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thank you, I'll keep it in mind

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A [nameref](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/commands/builtin/declare#nameref) can be pointed at multiple variables; thus making `srvVar` refer to any of your multiple arrays below:

```
srv_1=(e1 e2 e3 e4)            # I don't condone the original "eval" pattern, and no part of
srv_2=(e1 e2)                  # the question hinged on it; thus, not reproducing it here.

declare -n curSrv
for curSrv in "${!srv_@}"; do  # iterates over variable names starting with "srv_"
  echo "${#curSrv[@]}"         # ...taking the length of each.
done
```

See this running at https://ideone.com/Js28eQ

Comment: Love the nameref control variable ;)

Comment: Yup, you brought me around on that one :)

Comment: thank you I was just looking for something like that and it's going to be useful for the project I'm doing
I was already going crazy with trying

Comment: Hmmm, using `declare -n curSrv`, `echo "${#srvVar[@]}"` isn't going to do much... (typo -- welcome to the human race `:)`

Answer (score 0):

Charles has very good advice.

A tangent on your code: in place of `eval`, you can use `declare` when you have a variable assignment saved in a variable.

```
value="SRV_1=(e1 e2 e3 e4)"
declare -a "$value"
varname=${value%%=*}
declare -p "$varname"
```

```
declare -a SRV_1='([0]="e1" [1]="e2" [2]="e3" [3]="e4")'
```

And, as Charles demonstrates, namerefs for *working* with the array: `declare -n a=$varname`